# Jquery/Javascript: Buttons added dynamically with javascript do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, button

I have a code chunk of html:

```
<div id="chunk-1" class="chunk">  
    <div class="chunkText">Text<div>  
    <button class="addChunk">Click Me</button>  
</div>

<script>

$(".addChunk").click(function(){create_chunk(this.parentNode)})

function create_chunk(after_this){
    $(after_this).after(chunk_html)
    var i = 0
    $("div.chunk").each(function(){$(this).attr('id', "chunk-" + i++)})
    }

</script>
```

Now, this works, but only for the .chunk that is statically rendered on the page. When I press the button a second chunk appears, but that button does not work. If I add the html for two or more chunks to be rendered, each one works, but the buttons for the chunks it creates do not. What should I do?

Comment: **A word of warning about (almost) all of the answers below on this old question**: please see [jquery's live() is deprecated. What do I use now?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422069/jquerys-live-is-deprecated-what-do-i-use-now/9422110#9422110) -- use `.on` or `.delegate`, not `.live`.

Answer (score 3):

The event handler in the below line attaches the click event to the element matching the selector when you add the handler.

```
$(".addChunk").click(function(){create_chunk(this.parentNode)})
```

you can use the [live handler](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to do this. the following code will solve your problem

```
$(".addChunk").live('click'. function(){create_chunk(this.parentNode)});
```

Comment: @jAndy - The question says another chunk is added...so what would you delegate on? `#chunk-1` doesn't work here, you need a higher ancestor.

Comment: Ohh well,  for some reason I just assumed OP wants to duplicate an item within the div.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "live" jQuery function.

```
$(".addChunk").live('click'. function(){create_chunk(this.parentNode)});
```

The problem is that you're binding to a single element. The "live" option will monitor the document for any clicks on elements that have the ".addChunk" class.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
.bind()
```

with

```
.live()
```

or even better use

```
.delegate()
```

which is in your case:

```
$('#chunk-1').delegate('.addChunk', 'click', function(){create_chunk(this.parentNode);})
```

furthermore, go to [www.jquery.com](http://www.jquery.com) and read the documentation.