# jquery's live() is deprecated. What do I use now?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw on the jquery documentation that live() is deprecated. Is there a direct replacement function?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Of course:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/off/

The page for `live()` shows how to convert to `on()`:

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 114):

`$(document).on('event', 'selector', function() {});` replaces `.live()`.

`$('selector').on('event', 'selector', function() {});` replaces `.delegate()`.

`$('selector').on('event', function() {});` replaces `.bind()`.

Answer (score 9):

```
$('rootselector').on('click', 'selector', function(){
});
```

taken from http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look on all the deprecated functions of jquery depending on their versions

http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Please use my python code to scan all the live events and change it to $(document).on events.

https://github.com/pradeep-pk/jquery-live-event-changer