# Javascript: change event getting fired when input field loses focus

Tags: javascript, focus

I have input fields on my page and I detect when the user types something to enable the Save button. I also have enabled a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to let the user save. Whenenever data is saved, the Save button is disabled.

However I have a dilemma. If the user changes the text in an input field, does a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and then moves to another input field using the mouse, the "change" event gets fired for the input field that the user changed and this in turn causes the Save button to get enabled again. The Save button should not be enabled because no changes have taken place after doing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. What it appears is that the `change` event is fired not just with changes in text but also when the focus is moved to another field.

```
$("input.SaveMe").live('keypress change', function ()
{
    // Code goes here to enable Save button
});
```

How can I prevent the change event from taking place after saving. I thought of using some kind of flag but I can't figure out how.

Comment: [Brrr...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422069/jquerys-live-is-deprecated-what-do-i-use-now)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removing the detection for "change" takes care of the problem but this now prevents users from pasting text into a field and detecting the paste as a change. To fix that use:

```
$(document).bind('paste', function (e)
{
  // Add code to update flag to indicate data changes and enable the Save button.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore the event when that particular input is **not in focus**, in the following manner.

```
$("input.SaveMe").live('keypress change', function() {
    if (!$(document.activeElement).id == 'id_of_input') return; //if (!$(document.activeElement).hasClass('SaveMe')) return;
    // Code goes here to enable Save button
});
```

Comment: "SaveMe" is not an ID. It's a class name.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon The class is `className`. And your code will only work if there is one class only :)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine lol you made the exact same edit as I was about to press submit

Comment: The user can move focus from one field to another and both of them have the "SaveMe" class. You're code assumes that the user moves to something that does not have that class, so your code is not correct.

Comment: The OP could use the id attribute. I have added that as a comment next to that statement.

Comment: The code I provided is global throughout the page. You don't want to be working with IDs hardcoded in that function.