# .live() error for colorbox with jquery rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, colorbox

I have used `rails 4.0.0`

Also `jquery rails 3.0.4`

```
jquery.colorbox.js v 1.3.19
```

I have a link `<%= link_to "Upload Image", edit_seller_banner_users_path, class: "photobox" %>`

in js

```
$('.photobox').click(function(e){
  $(this).colorbox();

  });
```

it shows me the error as `TypeError: $(...).live is not a function` in firebug and the link redirects not opening the colorbox... Plz help.

Comment: it looks like you need an older version of jquey, .live() is deprecated and is replaced with .on()

Answer (score 2):

`live()` was deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 and removed from the source entirely in 1.9.

You've got 3 choices:

- If you have a 3rd party plugin which depends on it, try the [migrate plugin](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/).
- Refactor your code to use `on()` with a delegate parameter.
- Stick to an older version of jQuery (< 1.9)

Answer (score 0):

Its because

Since .`live` is deprecated  from  jQuery1.7.

Try to migrate/upgrade.

http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.7/

[jquery's live() is deprecated. What do I use now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422069/jquerys-live-is-deprecated-what-do-i-use-now)

Comment: but what do i need to change? I am not using live() in my code. it is showing error for jquery.colorbox.js

Comment: @Debadatt is it [latest version] (https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/pull/329) ??

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery-migrate.js in your application after the jquery.

Please check the http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/ and link http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js