# jQuery animation and live event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I load a page with AJAX. That page contains the following code (for div' movement animation, #1 moves it to the left and #2 moves it back again)

```
#1 
$('#flipper').click(function () { 
      $(".l-l").animate({ "left": -267 }, 600, function () {
             $('#flipper').addClass('flipper-h'); 
       });
});

#2
$('#flipper.flipper-h').die(); //to prevent .live() event bubbling. I guess
$('#flipper.flipper-h').live('click', function () { 
    $(".l-l").animate({ "left": 0 }, 600, function () {
            $('#flipper').removeClass('flipper-h'); 
    });
});
```

with that code I have some problems:

1) after first page load, the code #2 has a little freeze before the animation starts

2) after second (and more) page load the #2 code doesn't fire. Why ?

## EDIT

I've noticed that the code #2 is being invoked unlimited times (which's weird). But, I've fixed the 1) case by the code:

```
$('#flipper').click(function () {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('flipper-h')) {
                $(".l-l").animate({ "left": -267 }, 600, function () {
                $('#flipper').addClass('flipper-h');
            }); 
        } else {
            $(".l-l").animate({ "left": 0 }, 600, function () {
                $('#flipper').removeClass('flipper-h');
             });
       }
});
```

but the problem 2) is still unsolved. Any ideas ?

Comment: `live()` is *so* deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422069/jquerys-live-is-deprecated-what-do-i-use-now

Comment: OK, now it's `$('div').on('click', '#flipper.flipper-h', ....)`

Comment: Isnt it because u got $('#flipper') selector and $('#flipper.flipper-h') selector, so in second case both animation are called which looks like as no movement at all? (maybe Im wrong...)
Event bubbling is not prevented I guess..

Comment: Just reading about it, die() was also deprecated (same as live)

Comment: can you post how your ajax works or at least some states that your page has?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT3:** Consider these two codes:

http://jsfiddle.net/2zEZT/2/

http://jsfiddle.net/2zEZT/3/

In first example, when you use remove button, elements are removed with elements that looks like same, but they are not. Events are lost.

In second one, elements are removed but click event is binded again after that...

**EDIT2:** Based on your edit, try to use this function instead. It could behaves better...

```
$('#flipper').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('flipper-h')) {
        $(this).removeClass('flipper-h');
        $(".l-l").animate({
            "left": 0
        }, 600);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('flipper-h');
        $(".l-l").animate({
            "left": -267
        }, 600);
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** I suggest that you still use jQuery 1.7 so I did a little investigation.

At first, you put event onclick on the #flipper.

Then you call die on #flipper.flipper-h element. Which should destroy all live events.

After that, you made a live event on #flipper.flipper-h element, which means that all elementes that exists and will exists will have this event.

Now first click:
animation left: -267 happens,
then callback does #flipper becomes #flipper.flipper-h,
then live event is binded to new #flipper.flipper-h,

Second click:
animation left: -267 happens, but it was already there, so nothing happens at all
then callback does #flipper becomes #flipper.flipper-h, so nothing happens again,
now event is still bubbling, so second animation left: 0 is triggered after 600ms (this is probably your freeze)
now callback removes .flipper-h

Now I dont know how exactly does your ajax works, but it seems that die function removes live event from #flipper forever. So it can't be triggered anymore...

`die` function doesnt prevent bubbling. It removes live events.
`return false` or `event.stopPropagation` does

Comment: I'm using jQuery v1.10.2. See my post edit - even if I change from `$('#flipper').click(function () {})` to `$('#flipper').on('click', function () { })` the problem 2) still exists. My ajax function just loads the page to the div container

Comment: Is the flipper part of that container? Click function is binded to element in this case. So removing element and adding similar element again doesnt mean that it will have that event. If you removed it with html() or innerHtml() function, then click event is lost...