# typeerror $(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running into an issue, I have this snippet:

```
$('#new_comment').live('ajax:beforeSend', function(evt, xhr, settings) {
  $(':submit', this).click(function() {
    return false;
  });
});
```

which I use to disable the submit button, and thus disallowing multiple comments to be submitted, if you enter several times.

The issue is that I compile the JS on production into one file, and thus the code is available on all pages, and it seems to be affecting other parts of the code.

The error I get in the console is:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

how do I stop this from happening?

Comment: `live` has been removed some time ago. Use `on` with the delegate notation instead.

Comment: `live()` was deprecated and removed from the source a *long* time ago. You should use `on()` instead

Answer (score 3):

Which version of jquery are you using? jQuery .live() has been removed in version 1.9 and later.

use this instead:

```
.on(eventType, selector, function)
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

live is deprecated and answers has been given for its alternatives on stackoverflow earlier check this [jquery's live() is deprecated. What do I use now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422069/jquerys-live-is-deprecated-what-do-i-use-now)

Answer (score 0):

Use of `live()` has been depreciated.
`.live()` got replaced with `$(document).on('event', 'selector', function() {});`
`.delegate()` got replaced with `$('selector').on('event', 'selector', function() {});`
`.bind()` got replaced with `$('selector').on('event', function() {});`