# Jquery 1.6.1 issue with select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I used in my project `JQuery 1.6.1` library, but right now I want to use select2 plugin with `JQuery 2.0.0` for my all my select boxes and this makes some errors with some Jquery function like `$().live` and how to migrate this problem with changing the code?

My header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery-161.js"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery.min-2.0.2.js"></script>
<link href="<?=base_url()?>/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="<?=base_url()?>js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

The error in console:
[image]

Comment: If you want to be compatible with older IE, use 1.9.1 and fix whatever needs 1.6 - it is an extremely bad idea to run both

Comment: I know in this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422069/jquerys-live-is-deprecated-what-do-i-use-now I should edit my code but I dont want to change some thing in my code just how to use Jquery migration?