# Show/hide toggle wordpress doesn't work

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to put a Show/hide toggle on a custom html module on Wordpress,
i've tried some different codes and they all works on Fiddle but no one works on WP.
Do you have any suggestions? Here is one of the codes that i've tried.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
     jQuery('#content').toggle('show');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='content'>Hello World</div>
<input type='button' id='hideshow' value='hide/show'>
```

Comment: After adding proper jQuery library (that is 1.7.1), your code started working fine . check your question code now (run it now). `live()` is not supported to latest version of `jQuery`. Now they use `.on()`

Comment: Have you imported JQuery in your html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery's live() is deprecated. What do I use now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422069/jquerys-live-is-deprecated-what-do-i-use-now)

Answer (score 0):

i think its works so try it

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('body').on('click','#hideshow', function() {        
         $('#content').toggle('show');
       });
    });
```